# Spyware/Virus or something else connecting to a lot of SMTP servers

Tags: smtp, trojan

The other day I had a bunch of virus/trojan ware and I think successfully removed them.

I've scanned the computer with AVG anti-virus, Malwarebytes Anti Malware, Spybot, and Windows Defender.

Now all scans come up clean yet I can use netstat and see my computer connecting to tons of SMTP servers.  I think this is slowing down my internet access by DOSing my router.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your computer is infected, it is hard to know if everything is removed - it is possible to trick the virus scanners if the malware is intelligent enough.

I recommend you use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and basically delete anything that you think could be malicious.

If this doesn't work, as you have already scanned for malware (on top of that, I currently recommend Spybot Search and Destroy as well as Microsoft Security Essentials), the next thing is simply to reinstall Windows.